# HTN LCD - Ghosting Problem

Tags: lcd, crosstalk

I am driving a large, complex HTN LCD with 3 Holtek HT1625 LCD drivers.  There are over 700 segments.
The data sheet for HT1625 LCD driver is here:
http://www.holtek.com.tw/documents/10179/116706/ht1625v170.pdf

The problem is the ghosting effect, where the LCD segments are being partially on when they should be off.

All segments should be off in this picture.

[image]

This image shows OFF segments are affected by the ON segments.  Some kind of crosswalks, I guess.

[image]

I measured the waveforms with a scope.
This is one of the COMMON signal when the board is NOT connecting to the LCD glass:
[image: COMMON signal without the LCD]

This is the same COMMON signal when the board is connected to the LCD glass:
[image]

I am trying to figure out whether it is the driver or the LCD signal layout.  Is there anything I can do to improve the display?  I tried different LCD bias voltages but they seem to affect the view angles more than the ghosting effect.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am a design engineer at Focus Displays and am providing the link below to support ghosting of segment displays. Please let me know if this is not allowed and I will remove supporting documents.  Thank you

In some cases, ghosting can be a result of the internal traces giving cross talk. Some traces are too close and may need to be re-layed out. Here is an [article](https://focuslcds.com/journals/segment-ghosting-in-a-segment-lcd-liquid-crystal-display/) that talks about cross talk and some of the causes.

Answer (score 0):

I used get that when I messed up attaching the flex cable to the lcd display. Try a different assembly or put a different flex cable on the screen.